# Regex multiple @mentions with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mention

Why I am not getting the three mentions but the first one repeated twice?

```js
console.log(/(@[\w]+)/g.exec('i am mentioning @user1 and @user2 and @user3'))
```

Comment: Also, note that `[\w]+` can be shortened to `\w+`. No need to wrap it in `[]`

Comment: You may want to use `String#match` instead.

Comment: I need the index of each match, I immagine I would need to loop regex

Comment: The duplicate answers your title, the answer to your question is this: the parenthesis are superfluous. You create a group by using them and match returns the matching string followed by all groups. That's why it is repeated twice. Remove them on you only get the matching string `/@[\w]+/g`